# JQ Select by child object value with varying parent object name

Tags: json, jq

I have the json:

```
{
  "interfaces": {
    "UDPInterface": [
      {
        "connectTo": {
          "1.2.3.4:25925": {
            "user": "bob",
            "password": "aaaaaaaa",
            "publicKey": "foirncnqwpnqwopnqrrvn308g9h4b.k"
          },
          "4.3.2.1:24970": {
            "user": "sam",
            "password": "bbbbbbbb",
            "publicKey": "v09ervn4uvr78cweyclfirnfuq3c9pwper.k"
          },
          "1.3.4.2:41872": {
            "user": "betty",
            "password": "cccccccccc",
            "publicKey": "crnn497hg3j34f34uvrnfwmnriuhqrmoweje.k"
          }
        },
        "bind": "0.0.0.0:64660"
      },
      {
        "connectTo": {},
        "bind": "[::]:54887"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and would like to be able to use jq to print the contents of the IP address line based on the "user" value.  I can get close with this:

```
jq '.interfaces.UDPInterface[0].connectTo."1.2.3.4:25925" | select(.user | contains("bob"))'
```

However, this gives me only the values for the 1.2.3.4:25925 object:

```
{"user" : "bob", "password" : "aaaaaaaa", "publicKey" : "foirncnqwpnqwopnqrrvn308g9h4b.k"},
```

When what I need is the whole line:

```
"1.2.3.4:25925" : {"user" : "bob", "password" : "aaaaaaaa", "publicKey" : "foirncnqwpnqwopnqrrvn308g9h4b.k"},
```

However, I can't figure out how to build such an expression without knowing the parent object name before hand (each IP address:port will be unique).

I've been beating my head against this all day and haven't been able to figure it out.  Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: The whole line is not a valid JSON object, which is what jq usually deals with; I'm proposing some alternatives in my answer. What do you need that for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The whole line" is not by itself a valid JSON object. You can get an object with all the elements that match your predicate; this would be one way of doing so:

```
jq '.interfaces.UDPInterface[0].connectTo | with_entries(select(.value.user | contains("bob")))'
```

The output for your given input would be:

```
{
  "1.2.3.4:25925": {
    "user": "bob",
    "password": "aaaaaaaa",
    "publicKey": "foirncnqwpnqwopnqrrvn308g9h4b.k"
  }
}
```

Comment: no wonder it wouldn't work. this is the default cjdns config file.  we are doing this to help automate our set up.  Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **tostream**, **select** and **foreach** to enumerate paths to objects with "user:"bob" and return those objects in the desired format with **getpath**

```
foreach (   tostream
          | select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "user" and .[1] == "bob")
          | .[0]
        ) as $p (
     .
   ; .
   ; { ($p[-2]): getpath($p[:-1]) }
)
```

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
  ( tostream | select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "user" and .[1] == "bob") | .[0] ) as $p
| { ($p[-2]): getpath($p[:-1]) }
```